# Errors with using a timestamp in PHP

Tags: php

I am receiving the error: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$timestamp= '2013-01-20 18:20:20';

$datetime= date('F j, Y', $timestamp);

    echo $datetime;

?>
```

This returns January 1, 1970 Which isn't right. What am I doing wrong?
BTW: All of my $timestamp variables will be in that format. I am using datetime in my MySQL database table.

Thanks

Comment: Just for clarification also, there are several "timestamps" (each database uses their own). php uses the "**unix** timestamp" which represents the number of seconds since "January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC". The timestamp the OP is using is not a valid "unix timestamp" and so date() thinks the "unix timestamp" passed in is 0 meaning 0 seconds since "Jan 1 1970". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `date` function takes a timestamp which is an int
you need to call it using

```
date('F j, Y', time());
```

or

```
$timestamp= '2013-01-20 18:20:20';
date('F j, Y', strtotime($timestamp));
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for info on how to use the `date` function

Answer (score 3):

'2013-01-20 18:20:20' is not a timestamp . You have to convert it to timestamp. You can use strtotime function to do this.

```
$timestamp= strtotime('2013-01-20 18:20:20');
```